# Hotkey to refresh monitor input

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hotkeys

My two monitors are set to sleep after 20 minutes of inactivity. Occasionally when waking them, the monitors themselves wake up (I see the DVI input pop up on the screen and the power button turns from orange to green) but all I get is a black screen.

When this happens, I simply unplug one of the monitors and plug it back in. It appears this refreshes something so both monitors resume displaying windows.

My question is this: Is there some sort of keyboard shortcut or hotkey I could configure that would refresh my monitor's input, or am I better off continuing to unplug/plug one back in?

Answer (score 0):

I found this online using AutoHotkey, it might help you. It seems Win7 has a new way of dealing with displays that might be the reason why you have to re-connect your display:

https://randomgeekness.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/windows-7-how-to-set-up-a-hotkey-to-auto-detect-the-screens-optimal-resolution/

Comment: Link-only answers are useless here. Summarize the steps in the link, then show the link as the source